# What is a region inside a partition, not used by any filesystem, called?

Tags: filesystems, partition, gparted, terminology

gparted calls the region on a disk not belonging to any partition "unallocated", and region in a filesystem not occupied by any file or metadata, "unused".

How do we call a region inside a partition that is not used by the filesystem in the partition? (Suppose a file system doesn't necessarily fill its underlying partition.)

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I don't think it has a formal name. But it might be called "a memorial for the errors of a sysadmin", for it is probably most often created when a sysadmin begins a partition extension operation, without realizing that *this* combination of a filesystem type and old kernel does not support online extension of a filesystem, and the system cannot be rebooted on short notice... or the sysadmin gets a phone call in mid-operation and forgets to extend the filesystem to match the new size of the partition.

Comment: A region in a partition... not used by the partition itself? I can't understand what you're trying to ask here.

Comment: Do you mean the white bit to the right of the yellow bit, in the picture?

Answer (score 1):

Empty  (or unknown if the space is be used by an unknown format)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the white bit to the right of the yellow bit, in the picture? That is not a realistic picture of what is happening, It is just a bar chart of how much space is use in the file-system, not where it is used. It is file-system free space. It will get used as you add files to the file-system, and get bigger when you remove them.

If you mean **not** used by the file-system (I can't see this in the picture), then this is a miss-configuration. File-systems should fill the partition, but they don't have to.